# Add one to number in text document

Tags: terminal, shell

I want a terminal command that will edit a text file by adding 1 to the number in the text.

The entire contents of the text file is just a number.

I'm running the command through appleScript's **do shell script** command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
do shell script "echo $(( $(<FoO) + 1 )) >FoO"
```